# PHP determine if email appears more than once in SQL query results

Tags: php, mysql

We are working on a small follow up email script and now need to determine if an email appears more than once in the query results.  If the email appears only once then use email content A, if it appears more than once use email content B.

We are using a fairly standard PHP query and then using a while loop to tackle each row:

```
// query database followups for rows which fupdate = todays date
require 'user password stuff.php';
$today = date("Y-m-d");

// tourname, email, tourid, fupsent
$fups = $database->query("SELECT * FROM followups WHERE fupdate='$today'");
while ($followup = $fups->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $email = $followup["email"];
  // check if email appears more than once
  // the code we need...

  if ($emailcount === 1) {
    // include content A in email body
  } else {
    // include content B in email body
  }
}
```

Is there an auto-magical way to perform such a task?  Or are we limited to setting up another query / while loop to compare the email to every other and counting how many times it matches one?

Some additional clarification:

We are working with only one table, which contains: fupdate, email, name, productid (plus a few other columns which aren't related to this function).

Any duplicated emails would have unique productid

--- Got It Sorted ---

It was a tough choice as to the accepted answer, both had the same focus and were written within minutes of each other, but Qirel went a bit further with their explanation.

The final version is quite different than the original concept, as now we will first use the `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP by email` functions to fetch a list of unique emails to process, then do a 2nd query using `JOIN` to combine the followups and product tables to gather customer name plus product names and urls to build the email content.

My thanks to all three who provided answers/comments, as all contributed to the final ideas.

Comment: A simple join will tell you if something occurs more than once.

Comment: @Strawberry I thought joins were when using two or more tables, whereas we working with only one.

Comment: You thought wrong. Joins are for two or more instances of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement with your query, to avoid injecting variables directly into your SQL query.

To get the number of occurrences of an entry, use `GROUP BY email`, and then use the aggregate function `COUNT()`, which will give you the count of each email matching the condition in your `WHERE` clause.

The query then becomes

```sql
SELECT email, COUNT(*) as email_count
    FROM followups
    WHERE fupdate = ?
    GROUP BY  email
```

Where `?` is a placeholder, that we bind by passing an array to the `execute()` method.

```php
$stmt = $database->prepare("SELECT email, COUNT(*) as email_count
                                FROM followups
                                WHERE fupdate = ?
                                GROUP BY  email");
$stmt->execute([$today]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $email = $row["email"];

    if ($row['email_count'] == 1) {
        // include content A in email body
    } else {
        // include content B in email body
    }
}
```

Comment: We actually are using more data than just email, such as name, productID to build the sent email.  Does the `COUNT(*) as email_count` work if you used `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT email`?  Or do they need to be tied together?

Comment: When using `GROUP BY`, you can only select the columns in a GROUP BY or an aggregate function. However, using a JOIN you can catch more information. Is the other data, like product ID, distinct or are there multiple product IDs per email per day?

Comment: Each email would have only one productID, but any duplicated emails would each have a different productID.

Answer (score 0):

Use query with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT email, count(*) as email_count FROM followups WHERE fupdate='$today' GROUP BY email
```

In the `$followup` array you will have two keys: `email` and `email_count` which will show the count of current email.

Comment: And then, perhaps loop through the results and create an array of email addresses with more than one entry?  Then use `in_array()` to test which content to use?  Or did you have something else in mind.

Comment: What to do next is up to you.